# Correct Voltage Detection

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I have ran into a problem where some USB supplies drop below 4.6 volts. Is there a circuit that would block the voltage below 4.7 volts and pass the voltage when it is above 4.7 volts.

I have tried a brown out circuit in the below image. It is controlled by the zener breakdown voltage which is set at 4.7 volts.

[image]

[image]

This circuit works really well when the input actually reach 5 volts. It blocks everthing up until 4.7 + a little volts. The blue line is the output, the green line is the input from V1 and the red line is a voltage of 4.7 volts.

Where this circuit faults is when the input is between 4.7 and 5 volts. The below input only rises to 4.8 volts and the circuit then passes a dropped 4.5 volts. 
[image]

Maybe this isn't the direction to go. I have looked into a voltage supervisor, but those seem to want to give output pulses only. Anyways, is there a circuit that can block voltages below a threshold and pass everything above that?

Comment: Have you considered what will happen when your circuit connects the load which causes the voltage to sag again? You need to specify some hysteresis voltage in there too to create a difference between the turn on and turn off points.

Comment: It is better to regulate DC OK from the load which controls the voltage drop from any unknown source and stay within current limits of source. Otherwise you end up with a relaxation oscillator for a supply  source when load drops the voltage if you are not aware of this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a dedicated chip like this: -

[image]

It's a buck-boost regulator that will guarantee 5 volts from inputs as low as 2.5 volts. It has a RUN pin that can be used to set an under voltage lock-out at 4.6 volts if you want or maybe a tad lower. Apply the right ratio voltage divider from Vin to RUN to set the required UVLO level.

Comment: A little overkill IMO

Comment: @MAB maybe you can explain what you would do. Don't be shy, leave an answer please.

Comment: your solution will definitely work. But you can't deny that's a lot of chips to add to a design, not mentioning the challenge of laying out a DC/DC converter, testing it, making sure it works properly, without oscillations, etc... Of course it depends on your requirements. If I were to face this issue, I'd try Dwayne's solution first unless I have REALLY good reasons to go for yours.

Comment: A lot of chips? 1 chip and 13 small components. There's no challenge to a PCB layout of this type. The data sheet tells you what to do. Feel free to upvote the other idea if you think it's better. It uses 1 chip too and a MOSFET and 4 resistors and would probably benefit from an input and output capacitor. But that design can't work down to 3 volts or below so therefore gives the OP fewer options (besides being untried and tested). The MOSFET choice however, is very good.

Comment: I chose this as the answer because of what Tony EE said above. Attempting to block the voltage would create a relaxation oscillator.

Comment: @DrewFowler be aware that this could happen to this circuit (should you implement the RUN circuit I proposed) and it is only prevented by the presense of hysteresis in the chip . You should also be aware that Dwayne's anser offers hysteresis control via R4 so could work equally well but won't deliver the ability to work with lower voltages because the above circuit uses a buck-boost regulator and, overcomes the need to make a decision to deliver an UVLO feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using a TL431 adjustable Zener diode along with a P-channel MOSFET with low threshold voltage.  You can also add a single resistor to provide a little hysteresis.

Look for a class of MOSFET called "trench FET".  These have very low gate threshold voltage.

I'll sketch something out but won't have a chance to see if it actually works.  But you can either simulate it or build it.

Pick the voltage divider resistors to turn ON at somewhat more than 4.7V.  Maybe 4.75V or so.  This will drop slightly when you add the hysteresis resistor.

Sketch follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fApsU1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Resistor values shown are (very) approximate.  You will need to calculate the proper values yourself.

MOSFET part number shown was grabbed from Digikey.  It is rated as having RDSon max of about 0.1 Ohms.  Choose a different part if you need better than that.

You can choose whatever value of hysteresis you want simply altering the value of R4.  Do note that the value of R4 affects the threshold voltage slightly.